# What is the Newtonian Capacity of a subset of $S^n$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

In their paper ["Conformally flat Manifolds, Kleinian Groups and Scalar Curvature"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01393992?LI=true), Schoen and Yau repeatedly use the term "Newtonian capacity" for a subset of $S^n$.

I know the following definition: If $\Omega$ is a Riemannian manifold with boundary, then the capacity of a subset $K$ of the interior of $\Omega$ is the infimum over
$$E(u) = \int_\Omega |d u|^2,$$
where $u$ varies over all $C^1$ functions with $u \equiv 1$ on $K$ and $u\equiv 0$ on $\partial M$.

However, setting $\Omega = S^n$ does not make sense since $\Omega$ does not have a boundary. So does anybody have an idea how this is meant?

Comment: In wikipedia (scaled up one dimension) $K$ must be $n+1$-dimensional, namely the interior of $\Sigma$ (which is supposed to be a hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. So I cannot see how $K$ could be a subset of $S^n$...

Answer (score 2):

[Christian Remling](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253129/what-is-the-newtonian-capacity-of-a-subset-of-sn#comment622887_253129) is right; in Chapter 6, section 2.4 of Schoen and Yau's [*Lectures of Differential Geometry*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1333601), which covers the material presented in your linked paper, we see that the authors define Hausdorff measure and Newton capacity relative to the the ambient embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.